# Allow to collapse/uncollapse a day in the profile’s Reputation tab by clicking the whole label

Tags: bug, user-interface, usability, reputation-history

On the "Reputation" tab (sorted by "post" or "time"), the reputation changes are grouped by day ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor?tab=reputation&sort=time)).

If you want to collapse/uncollapse a day, you have to click at the triangle icon.

Proposal:

- Allow to click at the whole label (which includes the reputation sum and the date), not just the little icon.
- In case of sub-groups (which can appear in the "post" sort), the click should be possible at the label to the left ("2 events", the datetime, the reputation sum) as well as the triangle icon

  [image: Reputation history: one post has two events, titled '2 events', but you can’t click at this label or the datetime]

Interestingly, in both mentioned cases, the mouse cursor already turns into a cursor that suggests something could be clicked.

Comment: Your second request wasn't very clear to me, could you include a screenshot? I think the first one is a bug, though: the cursor shouldn't turn into a pointer if clicking has no effect (which can be solved either by making the entire area clickable, or only turning the cursor into a pointer on the arrow).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: I included a screenshot (taken from [my reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor?tab=reputation&sort=post) for "Jul 27").